# Array being changed while posting using FormData and axios post request

Tags: reactjs, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I am creating a Recipe Storing app using ReactJS and Django Rest Framework.
Find the whole code in

In a component called CookRecipe.js, I'm allowing the user to create a recipe. The recipe model in Django is as follows:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True)
    recipe_image = models.ImageField(max_length=1000, upload_to="recipes/images", default=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "recipes", "images", "default.png"))
    ingredients_req = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True), blank=True, default=list)
    procedure = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True), blank=True, default=list)
    precautions = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

The way I'm getting an array of the procedure and ingredients_req is by getting inputs from the user in different inputs like so:
[How I'm taking procedure and ingredients_req inputs as arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZuSl.png)

and then adding each of those inputs into an array.

Here is how I'm doing that inside the submitForm() function:

```
function submitForm(commence) {
    if (commence) {
        let data = new FormData();
        let created_by = JSON.parse(Cookies.get("info")).loggedUsername;
        let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
        let desc = document.querySelector("#desc").value;
        let recipe_image =
            document.querySelector("#recipe-image-inp").files[0];
        let ingredients_req_inp = Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll(".ingredient")
        );
        let procedure_inp = Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll(".procedure")
        );
        let precautions = document.querySelector("#precautions").value;

        let ingredients_req = [];
        let procedure = [];

        ingredients_req_inp.forEach((inp) => {
            ingredients_req.push(inp.value);
        });
        procedure_inp.forEach((inp) => {
            procedure.push(inp.value);
        });
        console.log(procedure, ingredients_req);
        data.append("created_by", created_by);
        data.append("title", title);
        data.append("desc", desc);
        data.append("recipe_image", recipe_image);
        data.append("ingredients_req", ingredients_req);
        data.append("procedure", procedure);
        data.append("precautions", precautions);
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:8000/recipes/get-all-post/", data, {
                headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm having while posting is that the array is being stored as:

```
["step-1, step-2"]
```

whereas, I want it to be:

```
["step-1", "step-2"]
```

In the console.log(procedure, ingredients_req) inside submitForm() function, before adding the array to the FormData I am getting the desired output:
[getting desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuZWF.png)

Here is the code for the post request in Django:

```
def post(self, req):
    print(f"data:{req.data}")
    serializer = RecipeSerializer(data=req.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    print(serializer.errors)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So I am suspecting that either the FormData is doing something to the data or the Django serializers are. The reason I am using the FormData object is because I also have to upload an image and as I was new to this, I followed the internet which said, "Use FormData.".

So the final questions are, 1)is there any way I can get this array to be posted properly? 2)why is this happening? 3)also is there a way to upload an image without using FormData because it is a pain to use FormData as it doesn't even give us the inner contents of the FormData when we say, console.log(FormData())?

Thanks in Advance!!!

For full code check out this git repo: https://github.com/RISHABRAVI23/RECIPE-BOOK

Answer (score 0):

If your sending an array loop it:

```
let a =['apple', 'banana']

a.forEach(item => fd.append(`fruits`, item))
```

if your sending an array of objects:

```
let b =[{fruit:'apple', price:200},{fruit:'banana', price:400'']
b.forEach(item => fd.append(`fruits`, JSON.stringify(item)) )
```

and in the Backend Django unstringify it:

```
let fruits = []
for i in data.getlist('fruits'):
        unStringiFied= json.loads(i)
        sizes.append(unStringiFied)
```

Comment: so, `a.forEach(item =>  fd.append("fruits", item))` just adds each item of `a` to `fruits` or does it create a new duplicate `fruits` field in the `fd`? @Asif kaif

Comment: Perfect!! That worked thank you very much. Also if you could just tell if there is a better way to post images?

Comment: no it won't create any duplicate, unstringify  in the backend if if your sending an array of objects: don't perform unstringify if it is only array

Comment: please up vote my answer

Comment: no other method, unfortunately

Comment: How do you send an empty array using formdata?